# Using \autoref on a table inside the figure environment

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, captions

I want a plot and a table to show up together in my document, therefore I used the figure environment, made the plot with `tikzpicture`, linked to this file, then added the `\captionof` command and then added the table in tabular environment. In my document refering to the table gives me Abb. instead of Tab.. When using the exact same code in a new document refering to the table by `\autoref` gives me Tab. as it should. In my document though it says Abb. instead of Tab. but the enumeration follows the one of the Tables, not the figures.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\addto\captionsngerman{\def\figurename{Abb.}}
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\figureautorefname{Abb.}}
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\tableautorefname{Tab.}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    %Figure
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates{(1,1)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{CAPTION}
    \label{figure}
    %Table
    \captionof{table}{CAPTION\label{tab:LABEL}}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            akbvk & laknflfk& kanfkf  \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

Refering to the figure (\autoref{figure}) and refering to the table (\autoref*{tab:LABEL})
\end{document}
```

The code shows a minimal example that works as intended in a new document but inserted into my existing document it suddenly doesn't work. Packages and the `\addto` commands are the same in both documents. My thesis is 50 pages already strong and neither do I want to publish it nor do you (probably) want to dig in it to find what's wrong, but maybe you have an idea what could be the problem...

[image: Compiled in my document]
[image: Compiled in a new document]

The first picture shows the code, given above, in my document (thesis) the second in the new document.

Edit:
I copied all the packages I use in my  thesis into the new document and then deleted one package after the other, this way I found out the subfig package causes the error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\addto\captionsngerman{\def\figurename{Abb.}}
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\figureautorefname{Abb.}}
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\tableautorefname{Tab.}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
%Figure
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates{(1,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{CAPTION}
\label{figure}
%Table
\captionof{table}{CAPTION\label{tab:LABEL}}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        akbvk & laknflfk& kanfkf  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

Refering to the figure (\autoref{figure}) and refering to the table (\autoref*{tab:LABEL})
\end{document}
```

Since I wouldn't want to miss on subfig, do you know how to bypass the problem?

Comment: Well, the problem is that precisely the more interesting file shows the feature but you did not post it... I suspect some missing `\label` after a `\captionof` command

Comment: The code given above gives different results when inserted in my existing document and when inserted in a whole new document (as you can see in the images). If I missed the \label it wouldn't work in either of these documents. So it must have something to do with my document/thesis. Since it's 50 pages strong I don't really know how to post it here, I was just hoping the problem sounds familiar to you.

Comment: Try to reduce your 50 page document to a version that still has the issue, everything else is guessing around

Comment: I tried to and copied all the packages I use in my thesis to the new document. After that I had the problem in my new document too. Then I eliminated one package after the other and the problem disappeared when I deleted the package subfig.

Comment: Ah, that's the way to go. Try to load `caption-of` (or the `caption` package) after `subfig`, it should work then even with `subfig` included

Comment: There's no change if I write "\usepackage{subfig}" before (or after) I write "\usepackage{capt-of}". That's what load it after subfig means right? Sorry.

Comment: I think the real problem is `\captionof` itself. It should not be used in a floating environment at all, unless you try to use `\captionsetup{type=table}` before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to put an explicit `\captionsetup[type=table]` before `\captionof{table}{...}`.

Apparently, `\captionof` should not be used in floating environment at all, it seems to grab the wrong `\@captype` content. In final, this will write a wrong anchor name to the `.aux` file from which `\autoref` grabs its information to determine the name.

Perhaps, the grouping together is not the best way at all.

The package `cleveref` provides correct names, however!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addto\captionsngerman{\def\figurename{Abb.}}
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\figureautorefname{Abb.}}
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\tableautorefname{Tab.}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
%Figure
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates{(1,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{CAPTION}
\label{figure}
%Table
\captionsetup{type=table}
\captionof{table}{CAPTION\label{tab:LABEL}}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        akbvk & laknflfk& kanfkf  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

Refering to the figure (\autoref{figure}) and refering to the table (\autoref*{tab:LABEL})
\end{document}
```

[image]